# Tortoise SVN PuTTY Fatal Error Connection Refused

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to set up SVN server on Bluehost.com with TortoiseSVN, and having some troubles getting things going.  I can open the Repo Browser, and usually see the bottom of my repo but if I try to move around or pull down something I wind up with a series of 4+ Connection Refused errors from PuTTY.  Any thoughts what I might look into?

I'm a total noob with SVN.